# Restricting Roles in JSP-Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP Web Project that I want to assign user roles to, admin and normal user. The user role has been redirecting just fine, however it doesn't, on the admin part. I would like to know where have I gone wrong.

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package ExamplePackage;

import ExamplePackage.UserBean;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

try
{       

     UserBean admin = new UserBean();
     admin.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
     admin.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

     UserBean user = new UserBean();
     user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
     user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

     admin = UserDAO.login(admin);
     user = UserDAO.login(user);

     if (admin.isAdmin())
     {

          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
          session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",admin); 
          response.sendRedirect("AllPost"); //logged-in page            
     }

     else if (user.isUser())
     {          
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
          session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
          response.sendRedirect("AllCustomer"); //logged-in page            
     }     

     else 
          response.sendRedirect("indexinvalid.jsp"); //error page 
} 


catch (Throwable theException)      
{
     System.out.println(theException); 
}
       }
    }
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ExamplePackage;



   import java.text.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.sql.*;

   public class UserDAO     
   {
      static Connection currentCon = null;
      static ResultSet rs = null;
      static ResultSet rs2 = null;



      public static UserBean login(UserBean bean) {

         //preparing some objects for connection 
         Statement stmt = null;    

         String username = bean.getUsername();    
         String password = bean.getPassword();   

         String adminlogin =
               "select * from users where username='"
                        + username
                        + "' AND password='"
                        + password
                        + "' AND role = 'A'";

                  String userlogin =
               "select * from users where username='"
                        + username
                        + "' AND password='"
                        + password
                        + "' AND role = 'U'";

      // "System.out.println" prints in the console; Normally used to trace the process
      System.out.println("Your user name is " + username);          
      System.out.println("Your password is " + password);
      //System.out.println("Query: "+adminlogin);
      //System.out.println("Query: "+userlogin);

      try 
      {
         //connect to DB 
         currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
         stmt=currentCon.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery(adminlogin);            
         boolean admin = rs.next();

         rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(userlogin);
         boolean user = rs2.next();

         // if user does not exist set the isAdmin variable to false
         if (!admin) 
         {
             if (!user){
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first");
            bean.setAdmin(false);
             }
             else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first");
            bean.setAdmin(false);
             }             
         } 
         if (!user) 
         {
             if (!admin){
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first");
            bean.setUser(false);
             }
             else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first");
            bean.setUser(false);
             }             
         }         

         //if user exists set the isAdmin variable to true
         else if (admin) 
         {
            String firstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("LastName");

            System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName);
            bean.setFirstName(firstName);
            bean.setLastName(lastName);
            bean.setAdmin(true);
            bean.setUser(false);
         }

         else if (user) 
         {
            String firstName = rs2.getString("FirstName");
            String lastName = rs2.getString("LastName");

            System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName);
            bean.setFirstName(firstName);
            bean.setLastName(lastName);
            bean.setUser(true);
            bean.setAdmin(false);
         }         
      } 

      catch (Exception ex) 
      {
         System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
      } 

      //some exception handling
      finally 
      {
         if (rs != null)    {
            try {
               rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
               rs = null;
            }

         if (rs2 != null)   {
            try {
               rs2.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
               rs2 = null;
            }         

         if (stmt != null) {
            try {
               stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
               stmt = null;
            }

         if (currentCon != null) {
            try {
               currentCon.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            currentCon = null;
         }
      }

return bean;

      } 
   }
```

I believe it has something to do with the if-else logic

Comment: You code is having redundancy. There is no need of using two queries one for admin one more for user. You have only two roles, so just check whether a user is admin or not, if yes then redirect to admin else redirect to user.

Comment: what if the user is not registered?

Comment: You should mention else part for invalid user.

Comment: May I know this how these `isAdmin()` and `isUser()` methods are implemented.

Comment: I mean, suppose I use if(user=true){redirect}, then else for the admin{redirect}, how could I use another else for the invalid part?

Comment: declared all the data on UserBean.java, public void setAdmin(boolean newAdmin) and public void setUser(boolean newUser) sets the boolean true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my comments.

In LoginServlet.java

```
 UserBean user = new UserBean();
 String role = "";
 user.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
 user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));

 role = UserDAO.login(user);//to get role either A for admin or U for user

if(role.equals("A"))//admin
 {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
      session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
      response.sendRedirect("AllPost"); //logged-in page            
 }

 else if(role.equals("U"))//user
 {          
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
      session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
      response.sendRedirect("AllCustomer"); //logged-in page            
 }     

 else 
      response.sendRedirect("indexinvalid.jsp"); //error page
```

In UserDAO.java

```
public static String login(UserBean bean) {
String role = "";
//one query is enough to get the role based on user name and password

String userlogin =
               "select role from users where username='"
                        + username
                        + "' AND password='"
                        + password;

//execute your query
----------------------------------
if(rs2.next())
role = rs2.getString(1);//role either A for admin or U for user
//catch the exceptions
------------------------------------

return role;
}
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _It doesn't work._ Means what any error? @AyapieTateyama

Comment: edited it with your answer. both the admin and user doesn't work now.

Comment: There is no need of `if(user) else` condition in your code. Read my answer carefully. _Doesn't work now._ Since your query is incorrect. @AyapieTateyama.

Comment: And don't delete the code from your question just edit your question by updating it with new code. If you delete the code from your question it will effect the ansswers. @AyapieTateyama